# ASSERT failure in QList<T>::operator[]: "index out of range" in QJoysticks

Tags: c++, qt

Im trying to implement [Joystick input library for Qt](https://github.com/alex-spataru/QJoysticks) and the most things are working fine instead of one. 
My joystick have 3-Axes. Every time if I trying to use the third axis, I got a error message

```
ASSERT failure in QList<T>::operator[]: "index out of range", file ../Qt/5.9.3/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qlist.h, line 549
```

But using the debugger, I was able to understand that, for some reason, the 4th Axis on the controller has an e.axis index of 4. The List that stores the axis assignment only has a count of 4 which means that the 4th axis index falls outside of the range of the List.

Debugger show me the issue in this code (`getInputDevice ...`)

```
void QJoysticks::onAxisEvent (const QJoystickAxisEvent& e)
{
    if (!isBlacklisted (e.joystick->id)) {
        getInputDevice (e.joystick->id)->axes [e.axis] = e.value;
        emit axisChanged (e.joystick->id, e.axis, e.value);
    }
}
```

`qDebug() << getInputDevice (e.joystick->id)->axes;` comes out `(0, 0, 0)`

`qDebug() << e.axis;` comes out `4`

Have some one an idea, how I can fix this?

Comment: I believe that the problem is with https://github.com/alex-spataru/QJoysticks/blob/master/src/QJoysticks/VirtualJoystick.cpp#L120-L181 `void VirtualJoystick::readAxes (int key, bool pressed)` function. I guess your Joystick has `Qt::Key_L`, but doesn't have one button written above. So in that case, it sets `axis = 4`. I could be solved by adding button dynamically.

Comment: The library you use uses SDL, and looking at the [SDL docs, the axes seem to be fixed](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GameControllerAxis). They don't seem to go hand in hand with the library you are using, which uses dynamic amount of axes, but does not map them to any specific axis.

Comment: like @thuga said the library design seems flawed... and the project looks not actively developed. Why don't you try Qt GamePad? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtgamepad-index.html

Comment: @GabriellaGiordano I was trying qtgamepad, with this my buttons arent work.

Comment: @UgniusMalūkas can you tell me, what should I exactly do to fix this?

Comment: @IljaGrebel it requires refactoring. It's hard to explain how to change. I just gave you the part where is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

However if you do not need the 4th axis and just basic 2D joystick movement just change the code to ignore the 4th axis:

```
void QJoysticks::onAxisEvent (const QJoystickAxisEvent& e)
{
    if (!isBlacklisted (e.joystick->id)) {
        if (e.axis != 4)
        {
            getInputDevice (e.joystick->id)->axes [e.axis] = e.value;
            emit axisChanged (e.joystick->id, e.axis, e.value);
        }
    }
}
```